# How do I import a video from an old Sony digital tape HandyCam?

Tags: macos, import, video-editing

Some friends gave me their old HandyCam and a bunch of tapes asking me to put them on a DVD. The model is Sony DCR-TVR103 and it records onto Hi8 digital tapes. It has a Firewire port also. I am trying to use import function in iMovie on OS X 10.6.

Every import though the video is super fast, like playing in fast forward. Ever seen anything like this? How can I import this video?

Comment: i think my folks have one of those.  i remember setting up a Windows box with some little utility that imported the video in native format; nothing else worked properly.  iirc [Hi-8 digital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital8) used the [DV codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV) natively.